# Invisible + and sometimes just doesn't want to work (On TexMaker)

Tags: equations, errors

To learn LaTeX, I was making some easy exercises (don't mind the size of the preambule, it's not mine). And, recently, when I compile the code into PDF, the plus signs are invisible ! And I really don't know why. Here's the code + the preambule :

*The code :*

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\input{C:/Users/miner/Downloads/Codage/LaTeX/Projets/Projets/preambule.tex}

\begin{document}

\arraycolsep=1pt\def\arraystretch{2}

On voit grâce au schéma que la forme entre la marche et le terrain naturel est un triangle qui semble être rectangle. Ainsi, pour savoir si le sol en terreau et la marche sont perpendiculaires, il faut que ce triangle soit bel et bien rectangle. A l'aide du théorème de Pythagore, on sait que dans un triangle \( ABC \) rectangle en \( A \) :

    \begin{align*}

        AB^2 + AC^2 = BC^2

    \end{align*}

\noindent~Or, on obtient facilement que si cette relation est vérifiée, un triangle est rectangle si et seulement si :

    \begin{align*}

        AB^2 + AC^2 _ BC^2 = 0

    \end{align*}

\noindent~Dans cette situation, on a \( AB = 55 \), \( AC = 72 \) et \( BC = 90 \). On a alors :

    \begin{align*}

        55^2 + 72^2 - 90^2 & = 3025 + 5184 - 8100  \\

        & = 109 

        & \neq 0

    \end{align*}

La réciproque n'étant pas vérifiée, le triangle n'est donc pas rectangle. Ainsi, les bordures ne sont pas perpendiculaires au sol qu'elle a créé avec le terreau.

\end{document}
```

*The preambule :*

```
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titleps}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage[cdot, squaren, mediumqspace]{SIunits}


\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1.6cm,vmargin=1.6cm}

\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}


\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{oldgerm}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\newcommand{\enluminure}[2]{\lettrine[lines=3]{\small \initfamily #1}{#2}}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[tight]{shorttoc}
\newcommand{\sommaire}{\shorttoc{Sommaire}{1}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{sistyle}
\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\newcommand{\m}{\scalebox{0.60}[1.0]{$-$}}
\newcommand{\dec}{{,}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\renewcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}

\def\bN{\mbb{N}}
\def\bC{\mbb{C}}
\def\bR{\mbb{R}}
\def\bQ{\mbb{Q}}
\def\bZ{\mbb{Z}}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\nvect}[1]{\overrightarrow{\text{#1}}}
```

Also, the code doesn't work when there are spaces between lines in the block `align*`. Is it normal ? But it works when there aren't, so I think it is...
I hope I will get some answers here !

[image: Here's the problem :c]

*And sorry if there are any mistakes in my sentences, I'm not a native speaker*

Comment: "easy" exercises to learn latex should not load nearly 40 packages.

Comment: Empty lines are not allowed in math mode. You should get error messages such as `! Paragraph ended before \align* was complete.` informing you about this. Thus, remove the empty lines inside of the `align*` environments.

Comment: you appear to have blank lines inside `align` they will generate errors. After any error don't look at the pdf file it is not intended to be usable. You should never have `\noindent~` and very rarely need `\noindent` at all.

Comment: You can use parskip package to have not an indent.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue, but you might want to clean up your preamble and remove duplicates such as `multicol`and outdated packages. e.g. `SIunits` and `sistyle` are both superseded by `siunitx`.

Comment: @leandriis IMHO there are many packages that can be removed or improved.

Comment: You comment in the question that you know the blank lines are wrong, but you post the question in that form, where the only answer can be to remove the blank lines. Please edit your question to show an example that has no error message sand still loses the +. Also I would advise not  loading `\input{C:/Users/miner/Downloads/Codage/LaTeX/Projets/Projets/preambule.tex}` (it does nothing useful, just loading conflicting packakeages) and instead just have `\usepackage{amsmath}` to define `align` that is all you need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

$a+b$

\end{document}
```

This shows a missing + and the log reports

```
Missing character: There is no � in font lmsy10!
```

Your preamble file loads multiple obsolete and conflicting packages, in particular it specifies the document font setup in multiple conflicting ways.

Do not input that file, just replace

```
\input{C:/Users/miner/Downloads/Codage/LaTeX/Projets/Projets/preambule.tex}
```

by

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

to define the commands you are using.

Unrelated to this remove all the blank lines and `\indent~` constructs which are generating errors and bad output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{parskip}% no indent for paragraphs
\begin{document}



On voit grâce au schéma que la forme entre la marche et le terrain
naturel est un triangle qui semble être rectangle. Ainsi, pour savoir
si le sol en terreau et la marche sont perpendiculaires, il faut que
ce triangle soit bel et bien rectangle. A l'aide du théorème de
Pythagore, on sait que dans un triangle \( ABC \) rectangle en \( A \):
\[% don't use align for single line displays
        AB^2 + AC^2 = BC^2
\]

% eek, no \noindent~
Or, on obtient facilement que si cette relation est vérifiée, un
triangle est rectangle si et seulement si:
\[% not align for single line
%    and never blank line before or inside a math display
        AB^2 + AC^2 _ BC^2 = 0
\]

Dans cette situation, on a \( AB = 55 \), \( AC = 72 \) et
\( BC = 90 \). On a alors:
    \begin{align*}
        55^2 + 72^2 - 90^2 & = 3025 + 5184 - 8100  \\
        & = 109 \\
        & \neq 0
    \end{align*}

    La réciproque n'étant pas vérifiée, le triangle n'est donc pas
    rectangle. Ainsi, les bordures ne sont pas perpendiculaires au sol
    qu'elle a créé avec le terreau.

\end{document}
```